# Is it possible to add a description on a Windows DHCP Server exclusion range?

Tags: windows-server-2012, dhcp

Is there way to set a description on an exclusion range within the DHCP server in Windows Server 2012, beyond the default of "IP addresses excluded from distribution"?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to add a description.